# is it possible to do this in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

MEMBERS TABLE:

```
 ID Resident    Gender      Location

1   Steve       M       S-55
2   Roger       M       S-42
3   Martha      F       R-20
4   Samantha    F       CC
5   Tom         M       S-12
```

I am trying to code an SQL Statement that returns a single numerical value.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(Gender) 
FROM Members
WHERE GENDER = M 
   AND Location CONTAINS 'S%'
```

The `AND LOCATION` obviously doesn't really exist in `SQL` in that syntax,  but I'm hoping to get the count of how many members that are `MALE` and reside in a location that has an S in it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hrmm, i tried both but returned 0 ;/ i need to investigate what im doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   Members
WHERE  GENDER = 'M'
AND    Location LIKE '%S%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
FROM Members
WHERE GENDER = 'M' AND Location LIKE 'S%'
```

Comment: `I'm hoping to get the count of how many members that are MALE and reside in a location that has an S in it` - your answer has the same mistake as the question, you are only checking if the location _begins_ with S.

Comment: @Bridge may be this is not mistake, this like is much more faster

Comment: It's much faster because it is doing less work - e.g. not what OP asked for!